# How to stop a function from returning unless a key press is made

Tags: javascript, canvas

I'm attempting to create a simple program that sequentially displays a number of letters where each letter is presented alone (see the figure below).  I'm also attempting to make the program work in such a way that the user needs to press a key on the keyboard before the next letter is presented.

I'm trying to do this by encapsulating each letter presentation within a single, almost self-contained function (singleTrial).  My problem is is that I can't figure-out how to stop the singleTrial function from returning unless a key press is made (see the waitForResponse function).  In this case, when the function returns, the next function call to SingleTrial is executed, making it so that only the second letter is displayed (because the first letter gets presented and then cleared in almost an instant).  What am I doing wrong here?  How can I make it so that the singleTrial function does not return unless a key press is made?

My ultimate goal is to make it so that I can iterate though a letter list, presenting each letter sequentially:

```
letterList.forEach(function(stim) {
    singleTrial(stim);
});
```

Thanks in advance!

[image]

Here is my code:

```
var responseMade;

function onResponse() {
    responseMade = true;
}

function singleTrial(stim, context, canvas) {
    responseMade = false;
    context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    window.removeEventListener('keydown', onResponse, false);
    context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    context.fillText(stim, 100, 10);
    window.addEventListener('keydown', onResponse, false);
    function waitForResponse() {
        if (responseMade == false) {
            setInterval(waitForResponse, 1000);
        }
    }
    waitForResponse();
}

function main() {
    var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas'),
        context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    singleTrial("A", context, canvas);
    singleTrial("B", context, canvas);
}

main()

</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I can't figure-out how to stop the singleTrial function from returning unless a key press is made

You can't (currently; ES6's "generators" will offer a way to do it, but it still wouldn't be the best way here). Instead, what you do is hook up an event handler for when a key is pressed, and generate the next letter when that event occurs. This is a ***key*** concept in web (and other) programming: Rather than your program working in some set loop, you wait for and respond to events that occur.

For instance, remove `waitForResponse` from `singleTrial`, and change `main`:

```
function main() {
    var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas'),
        context = canvas.getContext('2d'),
        nextLetter = "A".charCodeAt(0);

    document.addEventListener("keydown", function() {
        singleTrial(String.fromCharCode(nextLetter), context, canvas);
        ++nextLetter;
    }, false);
}
```

(You'll need to handle the `addEventListener` / `attachEvent` thing if you need to support old IE. From the canvas, I'm thinking you don't.)